# How to convert .properties file to json object in angular

Tags: json, angular

I have a .properties file including following code:

```
MultiLanguageView.language1=Turn off/on first language entries
MultiLanguageView.language2=Turn off/on second language entries
MultiLanguageView.toggle=Display works only/Display all entries

SearchView.headwords=Headwords
SearchView.headwords.tooltip=Headwords search
SearchView.entry=Headword
SearchView.entry.tooltip=Search in Italian headwords and in their French and German translations
SearchView.subentry=Subentry
SearchView.subentry.tooltip=Search in Italian subentries and in their French and German translations
SearchView.fullText=Full text
SearchView.fullText.tooltip=Full text search
SearchView.japentry=Headword (alphabetic)
SearchView.japentry.tooltip=Headwords search with a latin keyboard
SearchView.japentry.jap=Headword (\u6F22\u5B57)
SearchView.japentry.jap.tooltip=Headwords search with ideograms
SearchView.japfullText=Full text (alphabetic)
SearchView.japfullText.tooltip=Full text search with a latin keyboard
SearchView.japfullText.jap=Full text (\u6F22\u5B57)
SearchView.japfullText.jap.tooltip=Full text search with ideograms
SearchView.cinentry=Headword (alphabetic)
SearchView.cinentry.tooltip=Headwords search with a latin keyboard
SearchView.cinentry.cin=Headword (\u4e2d\u6587\u8bcd)
SearchView.cinentry.cin.tooltip=Headwords search with ideograms
SearchView.cinfullText=Full text (alphabetic)
SearchView.cinfullText.tooltip=Full text search with a latin keyboard
SearchView.cinfullText.cin=Full text<br>(\u4e2d\u6587\u8bcd)
SearchView.cinfullText.cin.tooltip=Full text search with ideograms

AdvancedSearchFieldSearchAction.HEADWORD_ADVANCED.results=Headwords: {2} additional entries found for \"{1}\"
AdvancedSearchFieldSearchAction.HEADWORD_ADVANCED.noresults=Headwords: no additional entries found for \"{1}\"
```

I needed to convert this into nested JSON objects to use ngx-translate in Angular 7. please

Answer (score -1):

You can create your custom loader with TranslateLoader on ngx-translate, the only thing you have to do is to parse the property file.

I do not know this file type but there is maybe a library which understand this file syntax or do your own one.

Comment: yes I can use customLoader but translations should be put in a json file that will be imported with the loader. right? I need to know how my properties file converting into a json object.

Comment: If you create your own loader, you do not need to convert it to JSON for loading it.
It's really as you wish.

Comment: as I understood,just changing the file format like below in loader not help to works. If you know how to do that please let me know. `constructor(
  protected _http: HttpClient,
  protected _prefix: string = 'i18n',
  protected _suffix: string = '.properties'
 ) {
 } public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
  return this._http
   .get(`${this._prefix}/${lang}${this._suffix}`, { responseType: 'text' })
   .pipe(map((contents: string) => this.parse(contents)));
 }`